# Is there a way to extract every nth frame from an online video without downloading the entire video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, download, video-streaming, frames

I'm looking for a website or app that lets you to download individual frames from a video as jpg without downloading the full thing. If there is no such website or app, is it possible via ffmpeg?

Comment: By the end-user: very unlikely unless `n` >> `GOP size` and MOOV can be downloaded and parsed. Maybe an online service has this feature.

Answer (score 0):

If the content is DRM protected, then encryption is involved and the likelihood of success is low.
If not, a program like Wireshark may be useful. That program intercepts and can record internet streams, encrypted or not. The program is very flexible but may take a long time to learn. I know of no canned answer. I've never heard of a program that can do what you want without doing some, if not a lot, of  programming.
There are other programs that intercept and manipulate, to some degree, internet streams. Wireshark is, what is referred to as, a Network Protocol Analyzer.
Google "wireshark alternatives."